# Why passing in props with spread operator works in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsbyjs which uses Reactjs internally.

In the file `/layouts/index.js` I have this code:

```
const Layout =  ({...props, data})  => {
..........
}

export default Layout;

export const query = graphql`
  query SiteTitleQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        smallBreakPoint
      }
    }
  }
`
```

### Update

The data passed in is the data returned from the GraphQL query.  It's not the data inside props.

If I removed the spread operator and/or the {},

```
const Layout =  ({props, data})  => {
```

or

```
const Layout =  (...props, data)  => {
```

it stopped working. Why does this happen?

Comment: That depends what the code inside Layout is doing. The above code has all props except data in a variable called props. Changing that to something else will of course cause different behaviour but depends on the contents.

Comment: @DominicTobias updated my question. the data variable comes from the beneath GraphQL query, not the data inside props variable.

Comment: It's definitely the data inside props, if you change it to `(props)` and console `props` you will see `data` in there. "This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element." https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Ooops, you are right. I tried to remove the data and only leave props there, then access the data from props and it works. Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Layout = ({ ...props, data }) =>
```

is absolutely equal to

```
const Layout = (props) => {
  const { data } = props

  // `props` variable is still available here.
```

Actually, you just taking `data` attribute away from other props while could still use props

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include enough code. The data is the result from the bottom GraphQL query, not the data inside props.

Comment: You are right... I tried to remove the data and only leave props there, then access the data from props and it works. Thanks~!

Answer (score 1):

Best way to understand is to use Babel REPL and see what code is produced.
[**First case**](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAMgQwJ4gK6wLwwBQG8B0hADgE4hEQA0MAJglAgL4CUMGAfDLqJCADYBTfHxABzbKXIRmAbh4R-QkeLoNmjAFCIU6PCCgALASQD6kogC4YAFgCsANhjVVCKwEYATAGYYLDUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2)

```
const Layout =  ({...props, data})
```

As you can see `props` contains original object passed to function (`_ref`) and `data` destructured from `_ref.data`.

[**Second case**](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAMgQwJ4gK6wLwxgCgN4AOATiARADQwAmCUCAvgJTYwYB8MeokIANgKYA6XiADmOYqQiMA3Nwh8hI8TTqN6AKEQp0-EFAAW_IgH1JBAFwwALAFYAbDEqqEVgIwAmAMwwmGoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2)

```
const Layout =  ({props, data})
```

On the other hand here you can see both `props` and `data` destructured from `_ref` (passed object)

[**Third case**](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAMgQwJ4gK6wLwxgCgHQEAOATiIRADQwAmCUCAlNthgHwwDeokIANgKZ5eIAOY4SZCAwDc3CH0HCxtegwC-AKEQp0ODiCgALfsQD6EwgC4YAFgCsANhhUVCawEYATAGYYahhpAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2)

```
const Layout =  (...props, data)
```

Is just an syntax error